# Site works in Visual Studio but not on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model

Site works in Visual Studio but breaks on server. Getting error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
I've re-published the project and it still errors out the same. I've pulled files down from the server and it still works on my machine but not on the server. What could be happening?

```
<div class="main">
<h2 class="queue_title">Queue</h2>
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{

<table class="inputTableLeft">
    <tr><th>Company</th><th>Category</th><th>Assigned Resource</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="CompanySelect">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                @foreach (var company in Model.GroupBy(r => r.Company))
                {
                    <option value="@company.First().Company">@company.First().Company</option>
                }
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="CategorySelect">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                @foreach (var category in Model.GroupBy(r => r.Category))
                {
                    <option value="@category.Key.Id">@category.Key.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="AssignedResource">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                @foreach (var resource in Model.GroupBy(r => r.AssignedUserName))
<!--Breaking here:-->{
                        <option value="@resource.First().AssignedADUser.FullName">@resource.First().AssignedADUser.FullName</option>
                    }
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
<table class="inputTableRight">
    <tr>
        <th>Incident/Ticket Number</th><th>RCA Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="IncidentNumFilter" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="RCANumFilter" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="QueueTable">
    <tr>
    @foreach (var grp in Model.GroupBy(r => r.StatusId))
    {
        <th>
            @grp.First().Status.Name
        </th>
    }
    </tr>
    <tr>
    @foreach (var grp in Model.GroupBy(r => r.StatusId))
    {
        <td data-status="@grp.First().StatusId">
        @foreach (RCAModel rca in grp.OrderBy(r => r.CreateTime).OrderByDescending(r => r.Critical))
        {
            <div data-rca="@rca.Id" data-company="@rca.Company" data-assigned="@rca.AssignedADUser.FullName" data-category="@rca.Category.Id" data-incident="@rca.TicketNumber" class="line @(rca.Critical ? "highlight_red" : "")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("EditRCA", new { id = rca.Id })" >
                    @rca.Id : Created - @rca.CreateTime @(rca.Critical ? Html.Label("expression", " - CRITICAL") : Html.Label("", ""))
                </a>
            </div>

        }
        </td>
    }    
    </tr>
</table>
}
else
{
    @: No RCAs in queue   
}
</div>
```

Comment: More information needed here.  You need to put in some logging or something like that to figure out what is causing the error or where it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably getting a null value from somewhere in this chain:

```
@resource.First().AssignedADUser.FullName
```

Add some logging and some null checks around this code to figure out what is null.

For example:

```
var firstRes = resource.First();
if (firstRes != null) 
{
     var user = firstRes.AssignedADUser
     if (user != null)
     {
         // Do your normal work.
     }
     else
     {
         // Log a message here
     }
}
else
{
     // Log a message here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. This is getting me closer to the solution. I applied a few conditions in the spot specified as well as the next location it started to error out at. It's no longer breaking. Now I just need to find what exactly is defined improperly. I'll update as soon as I solve it. Thanks again.